# Chrome reports a cross-origin font issue despite Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: htaccess, cross-origin

Chrome:

> "Font from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked from loading
>   by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access."

```
My .htaccess file looks like this:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
Redirect 301 / https://example.com
```

Then I added this to the bottom of the file:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

...and cleared cache same issue.

...then per this article:  [Font blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71630/font-blocked-from-loading-by-cross-origin-resource-sharing-policy-no-access-co?newreg=241bc0f137844c7b966a130ed3fccb72)

I added these lines and replaced my domain with example.com:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

My entire .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
Redirect 301 / https://example.com
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.example.com"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Any help here?

Comment: That `Redirect` directive looks out of place... that will either result in a redirect loop, but's missing a trailing slash on the target URL (which will result in a malformed request?!), or the user/request is redirected to a "different server" so the remaining directives are not being executed?!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I put a forward slash at the end of the domains in the <FilesMatch> ...example.com,...www.example.com ...</FilesMatch> element. But to no avial. Because I have both www.example.com and example.com as domains, Google treats them as two separate sites. So I added an .htaccess file to the doc root (/var/www/example.com/public_html) re-directs requests for www to the example.com. Site is hosted on a CentOS 7 server with Apache. Interesting: I don't get error if I go to example.com. Just www.example.com. Should I bump to redirect issue here?

Comment: Presumably you are linking to `https://www.example.com/...` throughout your application? Why do you have 2 `<FilesMatch>` wrappers? The second `Header set` will simply overwrite the first. (However, I'm still stuck on that earlier `Redirect` directive - I can't see how this is working at all?)

Comment: That's a really good question. I think because I wanted to cover both the www.example.com and the example.com just in case. The issue article I got the code example from didn't quite have the exact issue as I am having so I wanted to cover both domains which are the same site(application) if that's what you meant by "application". Also, the .htaccess file (which is supposed to point www.example.com requests to redirect to the example.com domain and it is not working at all. I have yet to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Setting two `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers doesn't work.  If you want to allow two different subdomains (bare domain, and "www") this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains) suggests you do this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
    SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?example\.com$" origin_is=$0 
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
</FilesMatch>
```

You then need to actually test to see if it is working.   You can use `curl` on the command line:

```
$ curl --header "Origin: https://www.example.com/" --head https://example.com/my-font.woff
```

As the comments state, your .htaccess file looks like it cannot possibly work.   The `Redirect 301` rule in there is unconditional, so it should be redirecting every request.   My guess is that is not being applied at all.   Maybe you are editing the wrong file.   Perhaps you have have the file name wrong.   Perhaps you are in the wrong directory.   It is also possible that Apache is configured not to use .htaccess.   Apache allows the file to have a different name if there is config like `AccessFileName ".config"`.   They are also disabled by default.   The config needs an `AllowOverride` directive set to something like `All` for  for your directory.

Comment: Thank you all for the wonderful responses. I no longer have the error. Issue was in Chrome but/Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16 issue.
Fix: (from advice above and hosting company) I took out the original code in .htaccess and called my hosting company. They suggested that I use the below code for my file which solved the error:


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: That code looks like it just redirects other domains and subdomains to your main domain.   You may have had an issue with calling fonts using absolute links on a domain that might not match the current one.